# Android layout design : Tablet first or Mobile first

Tags: user-interface, android

I just developed an app for mobile and in the process of upscaling the UI layouts to tablets i.e xhdpi resources.
 But, the problem I face is that I have to restrucure a lot according to xhdpi screen and have to use different images as the image resource doesn't scale up with good resolution.
 Is it a good practice to have all images in common drawable folder with higher resolutions and resize it accordingly in different layout types.
 This also makes me wonder, should we have to consider tablet first design and then move to mobile.

Comment: it's not the best practice, but it's OK, and I think it will work well with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the good idea to have all images in common drawable folder with higher resolutions. Why? Rescaling overhead. I think that tablet and mobile design should be considered concurrently.

Comment: Am just worried that using more copies of images under mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi drawable makes the app size big. So should I have to work on any compressions.

Comment: You have to decide where to put the balance - on app size or on performance. That's true, the more images you put, the larger the app. On the other hand the less files you put, the worse the performance. So it is always a choice, but you really have to use a large amount of images to break a reasonable barrier. If you'll compress image then again your performance hurts because of decompression process.